# Rails is not sending custom metrics to NewRelic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I'm trying to send custom metrics to NewRelic insights, but unfortunately it is not working for my Rails app that is currently sending default data to New Relic.

#### Steps to reproduce

I just logged in the console of the working application and ran the following command:

```
NewRelic::Agent.record_metric('/Custom/MyCategory/MyMetric', 5)
```

Unfortunately it never appeared in the Insights Data Explorer.

The configuration in the application is the following:

```
common: &default_settings
  license_key: <MY_KEY>
  app_name: my_app
  log_level: info

development:
  <<: *default_settings
  app_name: executive_alerts (development)
  monitor_mode: false

test:
  <<: *default_settings
  app_name: executive_alerts (test)
  monitor_mode: false

staging:
  <<: *default_settings
  app_name: executive_alerts (staging)

production:
  <<: *default_settings
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the New Relic agent:

- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm/NewRelic/Agent#record_metric-instance_method
- https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/c252fad410a5d41a65a827d633338af609f8dff6/lib/new_relic/agent.rb#L143-L144

  `metric_name` should follow a slash separated path convention. Application specific metrics should begin with `Custom/`.

Change your command from:

```
NewRelic::Agent.record_metric('/Custom/MyCategory/MyMetric', 5)
```

to:

```
NewRelic::Agent.record_metric('Custom/MyCategory/MyMetric', 5)
```