# Rails and NewRelic Custom Metrics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic

Has anyone been able to successfully implement custom metrics in a Rails application?

I can't seem to get custom metrics to show up in my New Relic application.
I can call the methods on the Agent without errors but I don't see the metrics anywhere in the New Relic application.

I am using `newrelic_rpm-8.16.0` and incrementing a metric like this:

`NewRelic::Agent.increment_metric("Custom/Test/Test_counter", 10)`
This returns `[#<NewRelic::MetricSpec 'Supportability/API/increment_metric':''>]`

However I cannot see this in my New Relic application under Metrics & Events. All I see are other metrics for APM, RDS, Redis etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen that answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868844/rails-is-not-sending-custom-metrics-to-newrelic?rq=2

Comment: Yes I saw it but it did not completely solve my problem :(